# The reals as a union of nested open intervals

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

My teacher was explaining in class that we can write

$$ \mathbb{R} = \bigcup_n (-n,n) $$

But how is this possible? since it contain only integers. I need some explanation about this. Thank

Comment: Unclear title..

Comment: The interval $(-n,n)$ contains a lot of real numbers. For any positive real number there is a bigger natural number.

Comment: What is the "it" you refer to when you say "it contains only integers"?

Comment: the bigcup is it

Comment: The bigcup is not a mathematical object, only notation. Do you mean the union, or the index set, or something else?

Comment: the union I meant

Comment: Do you understand the notation $(-n,n)$? (It is not an ordered pair, in case that's the source of the confusion.)

Comment: Here is yet another instance where asking the teacher is much more likely to help you than asking us!

Comment: What is the purpose of this website then GEDgar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any real number $a$. Then you can always find a positive integer $n$ with $|a|<m$. This implies that $a\in(-m,m)$. So
$$
a\in(-m,m)\subset\bigcup_n(-n,n). 
$$
As we can do this for any $a$, we get $\mathbb R\subset\bigcup_n(-n,n)$. The other inclusion is trivial, as each interval consists of real numbers.

It will probably help if you try to picture the union on the real line.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then there is an $n_x \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $-n_x \leq x \leq n_x$. This shows that $x$ is in the union you mentioned since it is contained in one of the sets of the union. Conversely, every set of the form $(-n,n)$ is surely a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and so the union of all such sets is contained in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, we have both inclusions and the two sets are equal.

Answer (score 0):

By the Archimedean property/principle of $\mathbb R$ , i.e., the standard Reals, for every Real x there is an integer $n_x$ with $n_x>x$. Then $x \varepsilon (-n_x,n_x)$  so $\cup (-n_x,n_x) =\cup(-n,n)$ contains all the reals.